# Why does an element flash green multiple times when search value matches again in input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a user types a search value in the input field, the code checks if that value is present in any of the list items. If it is and the list item was previosuly hidden, the matched list item flashes green and appears again, if it isn't, the matched item flashes red and disappears.

However, for some reason, the matched items that should flash green once when they appear again seem to flash multiple times (2 or 3).

You can test here:
Just type 123 then delete 3 and 2

```js
//jshint esnext:true

document.querySelector('input#search_input').addEventListener('input', search_value);
const logTextarea = document.querySelector('#log');

const list_elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul#list_of_stuff li');

list_elements.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('transitionend', transition_ended);
});

function search_value() {
    const searchString = document.querySelector('input#search_input').value.toLowerCase();
    const list_elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul#list_of_stuff li');
    list_elements.forEach(list_element => {
        const list_element_value = list_element.textContent.toLowerCase();

        if (list_element_value.includes(searchString)) {
            if (list_element.className == 'hidden') {
                list_element.className = 'flash_green';
            }
        } else {
            if (list_element.className != 'hidden') {
                list_element.className = 'flash_red';
            }
        }
    });
}

function transition_ended(event) {
    let element = event.target;

    logTextarea.value += `Transition ended for ${element.tagName}, at this point className is ${element.className}\n`;

    if (element.className == 'flash_red') {
        element.className = 'hidden';
    }

    if (element.className == 'flash_green' || element.className == 'flash_red') {
        console.log('Deleting ', element.className);
        logTextarea.value += `Deleting ${element.className}\n`;
        element.className = '';
    }
}
```

```css
#list_of_stuff li.flash_red {
    animation: flash_red 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes flash_red {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

#list_of_stuff li.flash_green {
    animation: flash_green 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    opacity: 100;
}

@keyframes flash_green {
    0% {
        background-color: green;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Input text and list in HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="search_input">
    <ul id="list_of_stuff">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>1234</li>
    </ul>
    
        <textarea id="log" style="min-width: 613px; min-height: 500px;"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also here: https://jsbin.com/yonejoqihu/

It's like transition_ended doesn't fire when the flash_green happens because the class remains. Not sure why?

Comment: You test the search string with `.includes()`, so when you type `1` it sets all of the entries to "green" because all of them include the string "1".

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, the "Flow" is as you type, list elements get hidden because they stop matching the input text, that works fine and the red flash only is shown once, but if you delete a character so some elements match again (they should flash green and reappear) then it doesn't work as I think it should.

Comment: You can also open the jsbin and press F12 to see that when you enter 1, 12 or 123 the only changes are the elements that stop matching getting the flash_red class and then the hidden class.

Comment: Don't you just need to replace `animation-iteration-count: 3;` with `animation-iteration-count: 1;`?

Comment: Yes, @GershomMaes I think that's correct. The animation will flash color-xparent-color for either green or red, because that's how the keyframe sequences is written, even when the iteration count is 1 however.

Comment: Notes: I would avoid in general using the whole value of `.className` as a flag. There's a `.classList` API that allows testing the presence or absence of a single class, and also adding and removing particular classes. It's much more robust and flexible; in a real application you're likely to have classes in the list that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @GershomMaes That was it, I thought the red one was working just fine but I guess I was just hiding the element before the other 2 cycles. I guess that means `transitionend` fires for each iteration-count?

Comment: @Pointy I'm not concerned in this case since there should only be one class using .className saves me having to do `.add(X).remove(Y)` and then `.add(Y).remove(X)`

Comment: @Daviid I *think* it only fires once, but I'm not sure; you can add a `console.log()` or something to verify.

Comment: @Pointy you're right, of course it fires once, the `Transition ended for LI, at this point className is flash_red` only appears once for each red flash, no idea why there's no `Transition ended for LI, at this point className is flash_green` though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253275/discussion-between-daviid-and-pointy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation (let's say for green) does this:

1. set background to green at the start
2. set background to transparent halfway through
3. set background to green when it's finished

So in one cycle, there is a green "blink", then it's white, then it's green again.  When you repeat that 3 times, it goes transparent 2 more times because between the end of one cycle and the beginning of the next the background doesn't change.

With `animation-iteration-count` set to 1 instead of 3, you'll get one cycle.